# C# How to get swagger to work when input is raw Json?

Tags: c#, swagger

In C# how do I get swagger documentation to work, when the API is reading raw JSON? Currently as expected, it thinks the API does not take any input.

I am using the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore nuget package. Is there a way to add comment to show parameter with type so that the generated file will have the correct information?

```
    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Process()
    {
        string jsonString = await GetRequestBody();
         ...
    }

    private async Task<string> GetRequestBody()
    {
        string jsonString;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            jsonString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        return jsonString;
    }
```

Comment: A far better question is "why are you reading directly from the request"?

Comment: you can start by checking out this site.  you can see how the swagger file should look.  and you can work in json or YAML -- https://editor.swagger.io/ -- you can also install the Swahbuckle nuget package

Comment: @mason Because the object needs a custom deserializer.

Comment: Why does it need a custom deserializer? And why can't you just register that custom deserializer with Web API's pipeline? You're abusing Web API if you read directly from the response.